# Axios giving 404 error after delete action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am running a React app which has a few methods to update user data. One of these features is to delete movies from a favorites movies list using Axios `axios.delete`:

```
removeFavorite(event, favorite) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(favorite);
    axios.delete(`https://flix-app-test.herokuapp.com/users/${localStorage.getItem('user')}/favorites/${favorite}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}` }
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.getUser(localStorage.getItem('token'));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

This is the code living in `index.js` file:

```
app.delete('/users/:username/movies/:movieId', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
  Users.findOneAndUpdate({ username : req.params.username }, {
    $pull : { favorites : req.params.movieId }
  },
  { new : true }, // This line makes sure that the updated document is returned
  function(err, updatedUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(502).send("Error: " + err);
    } else {
      res.json(updatedUser)
    }
  });
});
```

For some reason, I am getting a 404 error message when I try to delete a movie:

> Error: "Request failed with status code 404" createError
>   createError.js:16 settle settle.js:17 handleLoad xhr.js:59
>   dispatchXhrRequest xhr.js:34 xhrAdapter xhr.js:11 dispatchRequest
>   dispatchRequest.js:59 promise callback*request Axios.js:53 method
>   Axios.js:68 wrap bind.js:9 getUser main-view.jsx:58 componentDidMount
>   main-view.jsx:89 React 6 unstable_runWithPriority
>   scheduler.development.js:818 React 10 parcelRequire<["index.jsx"]<
>   index.jsx:21 newRequire src.78399e21.js:47 parcelRequire
>   src.78399e21.js:81  src.78399e21.js:120

I am unable to find out from where the error comes from, once the authorization is fine, the correct movie is picked up as a response and the messages are shown on console accordingly.

Could any of the colleagues here to help me to find where the error lies? Thanks in advance.

PS: @SuleymanSah provided the solution for the 404 error below, BUT I am adding my own solution as well - to the `axios.delete` action not working. Check below.

Comment: 404 error or status code appears only when, you write incorrect URL or endpoints

Comment: console.log(err.response) will show more info about it.

Comment: "I am unable to find out from where the error comes from" — It comes from the server, but you've only shown client-side code.

Comment: Can you share what  url you send in delete? Also share console.log(err.response) in catch block as Evan suggested.

Comment: @SuleymanSah, I placed the console.log(err.response) at https://pastebin.com/NP7yg8Zn

Comment: I think in the delete url `favorites` must be `movies`? Can you replace like this and try?

Comment: After changing the URL, the error message disappears and the ID of the favorite is displayed in the console, but the movie is not removed from the list array.

Comment: Can you check the answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, the 404 issue is gone, but the movie still remains in the list.

Comment: Can you add the Users model code and the document you want to delete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205872/discussion-between-cgobbet-and-suleymansah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url in your delete does not match the url in the express app. 
You should change `favorites` to `movies` to resolve the 404 error.

And to be able to delete the favorite, you should update your code using `$in`.

```js
app.delete('/users/:username/movies/:movieId', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
  Users.findOneAndUpdate({ username : req.params.username }, {
    $pull : { favorites : { $in: req.params.movieId } }
  },
  { new : true }, 
  function(err, updatedUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(502).send("Error: " + err);
    } else {
      res.json(updatedUser)
    }
  });
});
```

Depending one how you store the favorites, you may need to pull like this:

```
      $pull: {
        favorites: {
          _id: { $in: req.params.movieId }
        }
      }
```

Comment: @cgobbet did this answer resolve the 404 problem and delete problem? If so please don't forget to upvote and mark as answer?

Answer (score 0):

@SuleymanSah has gracefully provided the solution for the 404 error, but for me, the core problem - the `axios.delete` not removing entries from the list array, remained.

It turned out that `axios.delete` only could delete entries made by the app using `axios.post`. **Entries created straight on mongoDB array could not be deleted using axios**. So, if you are having a hard time deleting entries, try creating a feature to add them first and deleting them after. In my case, only app-created entries could be app-deleted.